# Adding Diet calories to health kit on iPhone does not update on watch App health kit

Tags: apple-watch, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I have a an iPhone app with an accompanying watch OS 2 application.

Both iPhone and watch app can successfully write and query diet calorie info from health kit.

If I write diet calorie info from the watch up and then query health store for the same,  i get the correct results back.

However If I write Diet calorie info from the iPhone app or enter it manually on the on health app ,  the watch query results never get the new entries.

Reading and writing health kit data is based on the FIT example here https://github.com/ooper-shlab/Fit-Swift/tree/master/Fit

```
func addFoodItem(calories: Double, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)?){

    let nowDate: NSDate = NSDate()

    let energyQuantityConsumed: HKQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit(), doubleValue: calories)
    let energyConsumedType: HKQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed)!
    let energyConsumedSample: HKQuantitySample = HKQuantitySample(type: energyConsumedType, quantity: energyQuantityConsumed, startDate: nowDate, endDate: nowDate)
    let energyConsumedSamples: Set<HKSample> = [energyConsumedSample]

    let foodType: HKCorrelationType = HKCorrelationType.correlationTypeForIdentifier(HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierFood)!

    let foodCorrelation: HKCorrelation = HKCorrelation(type: foodType, startDate: nowDate, endDate: nowDate, objects: energyConsumedSamples)

    let completion: (Bool, NSError?) -> Void = {
        (success, error) -> Void in

        if completion != nil {
            completion!( error)
        }            
    }

    self.healthStore.saveObject(foodCorrelation, withCompletion: completion)
}

func fetchSumOfSamplesTodayForType(quantityType : HKQuantityType , unit: HKUnit, options: HKStatisticsOptions, forDay : Int, completion: ((Double, NSError?) -> Void)?) {

    let predicate = self.predicateForSamplesToday(forDay)

    let query: HKStatisticsQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: quantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: options) {
        (_query, result, error) -> Void in


         let sum: HKQuantity? = result?.sumQuantity()

        if completion != nil {
            let value: Double = sum?.doubleValueForUnit(unit) ?? 0.0

            completion!(value, error)
        }
    }

    self.healthStore.executeQuery(query)
}
```

Is any experiencing the same problems or have any suggestions to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

The HealthKit database on the watch only contains data that originated on the watch.  It does not include samples from the companion phone.